# How to customer login with prestashop 1.7

Tags: authentication, prestashop-1.7

I am stuck over here for a long. I have to verify password on user login, but the password_verify returns always false.

Here is the code I have used

```
password_verify('123456789', '$2y$10$SB6R0jIknvmTNNL.h5rbd.FE1udyPiZHqr4g\/gMOYbgJtBWXLkkgm')
```

I am using Prestashop v1.7. Please help

Comment: Hi, have you been able to solve the issue?

Comment: No. I have spent lot of time to figure out a solution. But unfortunately, no. So temporarily hold this feature and proceeding with other features.

Let me know if you are able to solve

Comment: Yes i do have a solution. I'll post it later on today. Stay tuned (:

Comment: Yes i've found the solution yesterday, i'll post it later on today so stay tuned!